# Dual boot using Boot Menu F12 only

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I once installed dual boot Ubuntu along side Windows 10. After restarting it didn't showed Grub but when I pressed F12 for boot menu, it showed two options, TOSHIBAxyx Windows Boot Manager and TOSHIBA xyz Ubuntu. I found this much better then Grub as it automatically loaded Windows and when I needed Ubuntu I just pressed F12 during startup to load into Ubuntu. I tried to do the same after a few months of removing Ubuntu and installing it again but its not working. Can someone please find a way to get to this stage.

Comment: Did you reinstall in UEFI boot mode? That should have overwritten the old ubuntu boot entry with a new one. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I did a clean install of Windows in between removing all my previous data. Does creating a separate UEFI Partition does the trick by creating two separating entries of Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu in Boot menu?

Comment: You should only have one ESP per drive. Did you correctly reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode? Report shows details.